# createDrawerNavigator causes my page to go white in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem while trying to implement navigation drawer, i have stack and tab navigation working properly but once i initialize navigation drawer my page goes blank and once i comment the line my page starts working properly.
i don't know how to fix this and i need to learn how to make use of navigation drawer

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer,useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
    
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    const Home = () => {
      return(
      <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen  name="Dash" component={Dashboard} />
       <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginPage} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    );
    };
    
    const Search = () => (
      <View style={styles.color2}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Search</Text>
      </View>
    );
    
    const Dashboard = () => {
      const nav = useNavigation();
    return (
      <View style={styles.color3}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Dashboard</Text>
        <Button title='Login' onPress={() => nav.navigate('Login') }></Button>
      </View>
    );
    };
    
    const LoginPage = () => (
      <View style={styles.color2}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login</Text>
      </View>
    );
    
    
    
     const AppNavigator = () => (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={Home} />
         <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
    
    
    const App = () => (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
    
    export default App;
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      layout: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 32,
        marginBottom: 16,
      },
      color1: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        color: '#fff',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      color2: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: '#fff',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      color3: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        color: '#fff',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Once i comment this line the page starts working properly `const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();`

When i open my browser i found these error

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export * from "./reanimated1";
| export * from "./reanimated2";
> export * as default from "./Animated";
```

Comment: Are you using reanimated 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using reanimated 2.9.1, though i just install that after your comment but still the page remains blank without any errors

Comment: Where are you trying to use the `Drawer` at? it's not anywhere in your code

Comment: Yes i was actually trying to use it but since the page goes blank, i have to remove other implementation, in other to find where the problem is coming from that's when i found out it coming from calling  createDrawerNavigator() in my script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your contributions, I fix the problem already by adding

```
plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
```

to my babel.config.js file